# Can't access localhost from other devices on my network

Tags: networking, xampp, localhost

I want to access a website running in xampp from other devices on my network. Typing in `http://my-ip` works on my PC that's running xampp, but it doesn't work on the other devices such as my iPhone. I've already tried disabling the firewall.

Comment: `http://ip-address:port` this is how u have to connect..

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. I'm using the IPv4 address in ipcondig for my wireless adapter.

Comment: Please try going through some good tutorials to understand basic networking concepts. By default port number would be 8080. So try `http://ip-address:8080`

Answer (score 0):

You could try a "**telnet**" command from iPhone to ip-address port and check if the webserver is available:
http://www.esqsoft.com/examples/troubleshooting-http-using-telnet.htm
otherwise you can check xampp logs and read them looking form error or warning messages